# Debuging with LG K10 on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, debugging

I have a LG k10 phone and I'd like to use it for debuging my apps, but when I marked the debugger setting on developers mode on phone, it is not appear in Devices tab at Google Chrome. I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

Anyone ?

Comment: you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set USB options to `photo transfer`.